# Android: DDMS file explorer does neither show content of data nor sdcard folder

Tags: android, ddms

No matter which device is connected to my PC, DDMS neither shows the content of the data folder nor of the SDcard folder. All my devices are Android 4.0 to 4.3. Everything else just works fine.
How can I enable the access? thank you.

Comment: It shouldn't show the data folder on a secured device.  As for the sdcard, see if it is mounted at a different path than you expect.  If you open the adb shell you can use the `mount` command to see, or you may be able to view /proc/mounts through the ddms explorer.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the SCcard folder go to "mnt/sdcard".